# Production filesystem is at 100%. Move the datafiles to a new filesystem?

Tags: oracle, rman, tablespaces, datafile, file-system

As the title states our file system reached 100% capacity and I want to try moving the tablespaces datafiles to a new filesystem. I'm attempting to follow the steps from this link:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_oracle_move_datafiles.htm

My question is, since this is production, do I need to move the datafiles to another filesystem in Standby as well? Please advise if I'm about to ruin anything.

Comment: I hope you have set standby_file_management set to AUTO , if yes then  db_file_name_convert parameter will convert the files from primary to standby file systems.
so not required to move files to any filesystem in standby

Comment: @sarat - Do I need to delete the old datafiles saved in standby then?

Comment: What do you mean by old datafiles? I think you are doing datafile movement in primary alone.. so not required to do anything in the standby.

Answer (score 0):

The data file location on the primary database and standby database is completely independent. The location of the data files are written to the control file and the control files are not shared - they are different on the primary and standby database.

You can safely move the data files on the primary database without worrying about the standby database. It is handled transparently by the database itself.

You can move data files online if you are on 12.1 and the database is Enterprise Edition:
https://youtu.be/faq4wYdnhks
Otherwise, you need to have the database offline during the move of the data files.